# Does TimeFormat() change the date to your local timezone?

Tags: datetime, coldfusion, time-format

Does timeformat change the time to your local timezone?

I am working with timezones on an application. The users set their timezone in our database: (-2,-3,-4, etc). Then I get a date I need to display for the user, add/subtract their timezone value:

```
<cfset LOCAL.newDate = DateAdd("h",LOCAL.gmtOffset,LOCAL.utc_ts)>
```

And then set the variable to display to them:

```
<cfset LOCAL.dateToDisplay = dateformat(LOCAL.newDate,"mm/dd/yyyy") & ' - ' & timeformat(LOCAL.newDate,"hh:mm tt")>
```

When I view LOCAL.newDate it equals: `{ts '2013-07-08 08:57:23'}`

When I view LOCAL.dateToDisplay it equals: `07/08/2013 - 03:57 AM`

Why would timeformat change the value of the time? Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT: Added full function

```
<cffunction name="handleDate" access="remote" output="false" returnformat="plain" returntype="String" hint="Handle timezones and date formatting">
        <cfargument name="origTS" required="false" type="any" default="" />
        <cfargument name="displayTime" required="false" type="boolean" default=1 />

        <!--- Parse Date --->
        <cfset LOCAL.parsed_date = CreateODBCDateTime(arguments.origTS)>

        <!--- Convert date to UTC --->
        <cfset LOCAL.utc_ts = DateConvert("local2utc", LOCAL.parsed_date)>

        <!--- If daylight savings time is on, add an hour to users gmt offset --->
        <cfif GetTimeZoneInfo().isDSTon>
            <cfset LOCAL.gmtOffset = session.gmtOffset + 1>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset LOCAL.gmtOffset = session.gmtOffset>
        </cfif>

        <!--- Convert UTC date to users timezone --->
        <cfset LOCAL.newDate = DateAdd("h",LOCAL.gmtOffset,LOCAL.utc_ts)>

        <!--- Format date properly--->
        <cfset LOCAL.dateToDisplay = dateformat(LOCAL.newDate,"mm/dd/yyyy")>

        <!--- If time is needed, tack on time to date--->
        <cfif arguments.displayTime>
            <cfset LOCAL.dateToDisplay = LOCAL.dateToDisplay & ' - ' & timeformat(LOCAL.newDate,"hh:mm tt")>
        </cfif>

        <cfreturn LOCAL.dateToDisplay>
    </cffunction>
```

Comment: Can you give us a complete repro case of what you're seeing. Not with a coupla lines of code and the rest described, but an example we can copy and paste onto our own environments and run. This is just so we don't have to guess how you're doing some parts of this. Cheers.

Comment: I added the full function into the post. Just pass in a timestamp. There is also a session var called gmtOffset being used that is either '-6', '-5', '-4', etc...

Comment: Works fine for me on ColdFusion 10. `local.newDate` and `LOCAL.dateToDisplay` show the same time

Comment: as an aside you should pass in `default="true"` if you set your type to boolean in your arguments

Comment: Hmm, that is weird. What timezone are you in? What did you set as your session.gmtOffset?

Comment: I did something similar on version 9 and got the expected results, not the ones in this question.  My offset was 2.

Comment: When I pass in '2013-07-08 08:57:23.817' and return local.newDate I get {ts '2013-07-08 08:57:23'}. When I return local.dateToDisplay I get 07/08/2013 - 03:57 AM. The weird thing is if i replace timeformat(...) with hour(...), it returns the correct hour 8. So why would timeformat change the time of the value?

Comment: Just tried it on cflive.net and local.newDate and local.dateToDisplay are the same.

Comment: Ok this was only an issue in my dev environment. Thanks all.